One to many left join
Working in BigQuery I've got a table A with a column that has a item_id and a country_code and then another table B with item_id and country_region
A.country_code has values like 'US', 'UK', 'FR', 'DE', 'CA' etc.
B.country_region has values like 'US', 'UK', 'FR', 'ANY', 'EU'etc.
I'm trying to left join b onto a but obviously struggling with how to handle the 'ANY' and 'EU' classes where they map to multiple rows.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious here? I'd like to just have some conditional logic that handles how I'm joining, but I don't know if that's possible?

you need another column which states if a country is in the EU or not. ANY is simple , you  need a CASE WHEN and when is it any you set A.Country_code ELSE b.country_region

Not familiar with BigQuery, but with SQL you could put a table in between which maps regions to countries and countries to countries.  So US maps to US, EU maps to FR, EU maps to UK, etc.  It would be a two-column table which takes region on one side and country code on the other.

Thanks @nbk sorry to be a pain, but is that CASE WHEN in the join? or somewhere else? Just trying to think where these pieces go.

@TimMorton how would the join then work? If I have a column with a mix of values from each of the lookup columns?

@mccinthenyc yes the case belngs to the ON clause
